# when i hit the enemy in my game it doesn't die

Tags: python, pygame

In my game, which I've coded using Pygame, I'm encountering an issue where, upon hitting an enemy with projectiles, it appears that the enemy's health is not decreasing, regardless of how many times and for how long I hit them. This is leading to enemies not being defeated as expected. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue in my code.

```
   import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *


# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()


# Define colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


# Define the dimensions of the chessboard
BOARD_SIZE = 26
SQUARE_SIZE = 26
BOARD_WIDTH = BOARD_SIZE * SQUARE_SIZE
BOARD_HEIGHT = BOARD_SIZE * SQUARE_SIZE


# Create the game window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dungeon Horse Breeder")


# Set the game icon
game_icon = pygame.image.load("trojan-horse.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(game_icon)


# Load the farmer.png image and resize it
farmer_image = pygame.image.load("farmer.png").convert_alpha()
FARMER_WIDTH = 30  # Adjust the width as needed
FARMER_HEIGHT = 30  # Adjust the height as needed
farmer_image = pygame.transform.scale(farmer_image, (FARMER_WIDTH, FARMER_HEIGHT))


# Load the dungeon.png image and resize it
dungeon_image = pygame.image.load("dungeon.png").convert_alpha()
DUNGEON_WIDTH = 500  # Adjust the width as needed
DUNGEON_HEIGHT = 500  # Adjust the height as needed
dungeon_image = pygame.transform.scale(dungeon_image, (DUNGEON_WIDTH, DUNGEON_HEIGHT))


# Load enemy images and resize them
enemy_images = [
   pygame.image.load("saatan.png").convert_alpha(),
   pygame.image.load("evil.png").convert_alpha(),
   pygame.image.load("devil.png").convert_alpha(),
   pygame.image.load("bulldog.png").convert_alpha()
]
ENEMY_WIDTH = 30
ENEMY_HEIGHT = 30
for i in range(len(enemy_images)):
   enemy_images[i] = pygame.transform.scale(enemy_images[i], (ENEMY_WIDTH, ENEMY_HEIGHT))


# Define the speed of the enemies
ENEMY_SPEEDS = [.5, .1, 1.5, 1]


# Define the health and defense of the enemies
ENEMY_HEALTH = [1, 1, 1, 1]


# Create the game clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()




# Breeder
class MainCharacter(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()


       # Use the resized character image
       self.image = farmer_image


       # Set the character's rect (hitbox) and initial position
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (100, 100)  # Initial position (adjust as needed)


       # Character attributes
       self.health = 100
       self.hunger = 0
       self.happiness = 100


       # Create a timer for shooting cooldown
       self.shoot_cooldown = 0


   def update(self):
       # Add any character updates here (e.g., handling health, hunger, happiness, etc.)
       pass


   def move(self, dx, dy):
       # Move the character by dx and dy
       new_x = self.rect.x + dx
       new_y = self.rect.y + dy


       # Check if the new position is within the screen boundaries
       if 0 <= new_x <= BOARD_WIDTH - FARMER_WIDTH:
           self.rect.x = new_x
       else:
           # If the new position would be outside the screen on the x-axis, prevent movement
           dx = 0


       if 0 <= new_y <= BOARD_HEIGHT - FARMER_HEIGHT:
           self.rect.y = new_y
       else:
           # If the new position would be outside the screen on the y-axis, prevent movement
           dy = 0


       return dx, dy


   def shoot(self):
       # Shoot a projectile
       self.shoot_cooldown -= .5
       keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       if keys[K_w] and self.shoot_cooldown <= 0:
           projectile = Projectile(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)
           projectile_group.add(projectile)
           self.shoot_cooldown = 20  # Cooldown between shots




class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self, enemy_type):
       super().__init__()


       # Select enemy image based on enemy_type
       self.image = enemy_images[enemy_type]


       # Set the enemy's rect (hitbox) and initial position
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.x = random.randint(BOARD_WIDTH + ENEMY_WIDTH, BOARD_WIDTH + DUNGEON_WIDTH - ENEMY_WIDTH)
       self.rect.y = random.randint(0, BOARD_HEIGHT - ENEMY_HEIGHT)


       # Enemy attributes based on enemy_type
       self.health = ENEMY_HEALTH[enemy_type]
       self.speed = ENEMY_SPEEDS[enemy_type]


   def update(self):
       # Enemy movement
       self.rect.x -= self.speed


       # Check if the enemy is outside the screen
       if self.rect.right < 0:
           self.kill()




class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self, x, y):
       super().__init__()


       # Set the projectile image and position
       self.image = pygame.Surface((5, 5))
       self.image.fill(RED)
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (x, y)


       # Projectile speed
       self.speed = 5


   def update(self):
       # Move the projectile
       self.rect.x += self.speed


       # Check if the projectile is outside the screen
       if self.rect.left > BOARD_WIDTH:
           self.kill()




# Create the main character
main_character = MainCharacter()


# Create a sprite group to hold the main character
character_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
character_group.add(main_character)


# Create a sprite group to hold enemies
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


# Create a sprite group to hold projectiles
projectile_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


# Create a breeding section on the top right of the screen
breeding_section_width = 200
breeding_section_height = 100
breeding_section_color = GREEN
breeding_section_rect = pygame.Rect(BOARD_WIDTH - breeding_section_width, 0, breeding_section_width,
                                   breeding_section_height)


# Create a door on the left side of the screen
DOOR_WIDTH = 30
DOOR_HEIGHT = BOARD_HEIGHT
door_color = RED
door_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, DOOR_WIDTH, DOOR_HEIGHT)


# New area (dungeon) properties
dungeon_area_width = 300
dungeon_area_height = 300
dungeon_area_color = (128, 0, 128)  # Purple color
dungeon_area_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, dungeon_area_width, dungeon_area_height)
inside_dungeon = False




# Function to create random enemies in the dungeon
def create_random_enemies():
   for _ in range(3):
       enemy_type = random.randint(0, len(enemy_images) - 1)
       enemy = Enemy(enemy_type)
       enemy_group.add(enemy)




# New area (dungeon) game loop
def dungeon_game_loop():
   global inside_dungeon  # Use the global variable to control entering/exiting the dungeon area


   create_random_enemies()  # Create random enemies in the dungeon


   while inside_dungeon:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == QUIT:
               inside_dungeon = False
               pygame.quit()
               quit()


       # Get keys that are currently held down
       keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       dx, dy = 0, 0
       if keys[K_LEFT]:
           dx = -1
       if keys[K_RIGHT]:
           dx = 1
       if keys[K_UP]:
           dy = -1
       if keys[K_DOWN]:
           dy = 1


       dx, dy = main_character.move(dx, dy)


       # Check if the main character is touching the door to go back to the main area
       if door_rect.colliderect(main_character.rect):
           inside_dungeon = False
           main_character.rect.x = BOARD_WIDTH - FARMER_WIDTH - 1  # Place the character just outside the door
           main_character.rect.y = random.randint(0, BOARD_HEIGHT - FARMER_HEIGHT)  # Random Y position


       # Update the game state
       character_group.update()
       enemy_group.update()
       projectile_group.update()


       # Check for collisions between enemies and projectiles
       enemy_hit_dict = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_group, projectile_group, False, True)
       for enemy, projectiles in enemy_hit_dict.items():
           # Deal damage to the enemy for each projectile that hit it
           for projectile in projectiles:
               enemy.health -= 0.05 * enemy.health  # Each projectile hits an enemy for 5% of its health
               if enemy.health <= 0:
                   enemy.kill()  # Remove the enemy from the group


       # Check for shooting in the dungeon
       main_character.shoot()


       # Draw the dungeon area
       screen.fill(dungeon_area_color)
       screen.blit(dungeon_image, dungeon_area_rect)  # Draw the dungeon layout
       character_group.draw(screen)
       enemy_group.draw(screen)
       projectile_group.draw(screen)


       # Update the display
       pygame.display.update()
       clock.tick(60)




# Main game loop
running = True
while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
           running = False


   # Check if the farmer is in the breeding section
   if breeding_section_rect.colliderect(main_character.rect):
       inside_dungeon = True
       main_character.rect.x = DOOR_WIDTH  # Place the character just outside the door
       main_character.rect.y = random.randint(0, BOARD_HEIGHT - FARMER_HEIGHT)  # Random Y position


   # Get keys that are currently held down
   keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
   dx, dy = 0, 0
   if keys[K_LEFT]:
       dx = -1
   if keys[K_RIGHT]:
       dx = 1
   if keys[K_UP]:
       dy = -1
   if keys[K_DOWN]:
       dy = 1


   dx, dy = main_character.move(dx, dy)


   # Check for shooting in the main area
   main_character.shoot()


   # Update the game state
   character_group.update()
   enemy_group.update()
   projectile_group.update()


   # Check for collisions between enemies and projectiles
   enemy_hit_dict = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_group, projectile_group, False, True)
   for enemy, projectiles in enemy_hit_dict.items():
       # Deal damage to the enemy for each projectile that hit it
       for projectile in projectiles:
           enemy.health -= 0.05 * enemy.health  # Each projectile hits an enemy for 5% of its health
           if enemy.health <= 0:
               enemy.kill()  # Remove the enemy from the group


   # Draw the game elements
   screen.fill(BLUE)  # Fill the screen with blue color


   # Draw the door on the left side
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, door_color, door_rect)


   # Draw the breeding section
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, breeding_section_color, breeding_section_rect)


   character_group.draw(screen)
   enemy_group.draw(screen)
   projectile_group.draw(screen)


   # Update the display
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(60)


   # If inside the dungeon, run the dungeon game loop
   if inside_dungeon:
       dungeon_game_loop()


# Quit Pygame
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: you probably wanted to multiply it with the enemies max health

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding to your code:

```py
enemy.health -= 0.05 * enemy.health 
if enemy.health <= 0:
    enemy.kill()
```

`enemy.health -= 0.05 * enemy.health` never leads to `enemy.health <= 0`, because as long `enemy.health` is positive, no matter what value `enemy.health` has `0.05 * enemy.health` is always smaller and thus `enemy.health - 0.05 * enemy.health` is always greater than 0.

```
x - 0.05 * x > 0, if x > 0
```

I propose to subtract a constant. Since health is intialized with 1, subtracting 0.05 will kill the enemy after 20 hits:

```py
enemy.health -= 0.05 
if enemy.health <= 0:
    enemy.kill()
```

Comment: @JonSG No I meant that `enemy.health * 0.5` is alwaya smaller than `enemy.health` as long `enemy.health` is positive and thus `enemy.health - 0.05 * enemy.health` is always greater than 0

Comment: if you could how would you rewrite my code to do that. Because i solved the issue of not having the enemies killed when you hit it with the projectile.   for projectile in projectiles:
           enemy.health -= 1 * enemy.health  # Each projectile hits an enemy for 5% of its health
           if enemy.health <= 0:
               enemy.kill()                                                                                                     But now i can only hit an enemy once and it dies

Comment: @ManyDog As explained in my answer: `enemy.health -= 0.05`

Comment: oh you meant to delete * enemy health in my code. I was confused thank you. i still have to tweak this stuff and add more functions to how my game works but it's definitely better with your import on my code